# Font awesome icons not showning

Tags: css, font-awesome

Question related to: [How can i reduce the size of the background of an image or remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202274/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-background-of-an-image-or-remove-it)

left and right arrows not showning in the page, tried many css font and content, i think there's something missing

```css
@media screen and (max-width:800px){
 .my-view-detail .timeline-posts .owl-prev span,
 .my-view-detail .timeline-posts .owl-next span{
  display: none;
 }

 .mobile-next-prev{
  margin-top: -50px;
 }
 .set-button-left{
  position: inherit;
  float: left;
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f104";

 }
 .set-button-right{
  position: inherit;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f105";
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width:680px){
 .mobile-next-prev{
  margin-top: -110px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 1000 !important;

 }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="row .mobile-next-prev">
 <div class="col-sm-12">

  <!-- pre start -->
  <?php if($previous){ ?>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('details/'.$previous); ?>" class=".set-button-left" ></a>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- pre end -->
  
  <!-- next start -->
  <?php if($nexts){  ?>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('details/'.$nexts); ?>" class=".set-button-right" ></a>
  <!-- next end -->
  <?php } ?>
 </div>

</div>
```

Do i need to include css file or something ?

Hope someone can help, i was working on it for hours without sucess

Comment: Are you referencing the font-awesome library in your HTML? Here how to get started:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Comment: i did `<head>
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--load all styles -->
</head>`
nothing changed

Comment: It that the actual line of code? If so, it's looking for all.css in a folder literally named "/your-path-to-fontawesome..."

Comment: @LarryBud no sorry, it's ../../assets/css/all.css

Comment: but that didn't do anything, my question is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202274/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-background-of-an-image-or-remove-it

Answer (score -1):

I used fontawesome 4.7v only, You may get solution for your question here =>[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712987/font-awesome-5-on-pseudo-elements)